# Unwanted white space when defining macro in animatedinline environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I want to create an animation which consists of some text put in a bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [use as bounding box] (0, 0) rectangle (\textwidth,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newframe
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

When I put some macros at the beginning of animatedinline environment my animation gets indented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{3}
\global\def\myfunc{}
\global\def\myfunc{}
\global\def\myfunc{}
\global\def\myfunc{}
\global\def\myfunc{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [use as bounding box] (0, 0) rectangle (\textwidth,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newframe
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  the free, community driven Questions and Answers site for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems.

Here is some information to help you get started and to make your work with this site a pleasant experience for you and all other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the linebreaks are interpreted as spaces. You can comment them out using `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{3}%
\global\def\myfunc{}%
\global\def\myfunc{}%
\global\def\myfunc{}%
\global\def\myfunc{}%
\global\def\myfunc{}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [use as bounding box] (0, 0) rectangle (\textwidth,10);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\newframe
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user3044825 glad to hear that. If it solved your problem please accept the answer.